# How to set textview under each other in linearlayout

Tags: android

What I want is that I can have 1 ImageView on the left and next to the imageview 2 textviews under each other. I can't get the second textview under the textview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/displayImage"
    android:layout_width="67dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_name"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="20sp"

    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_description"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks now:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwExO.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPO8V.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/displayImage"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="Left text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:text="Right text" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can nest containers like `LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout`, `FrameLayout`, etc inside each other to create complex Layouts.

Also, I'd advise knowing what each tags do by Googling them before using them inappropriately anywhere inside your layout. It needed me solid 5 minutes to fix your layout because you added `layout_weight` basically anywhere you pleased!

Comment: I have 1 more question, when I add a marginTop it is changing the bottom margin and when I type marginBottom it is still changing the bottom margin. Why can I not change the top margin?

Comment: I'll have to see what the problem is and where you're trying to apply the margin. Sorry for the late reply, I didn't get notified of your comment. If you still have that problem, make sure you tag me when you comment. @DoingGreat

Answer (score 0):

Your linear layout orientation is horizontal, so you can't get textviews vertically aligned unless you take one more linear layout for the 2 textviews with vertical orientation. Otherwise, you can do this with a single Relative layout.

Here is the structure

```
<LinearLayout> - horizontal orientation
<Imageview/>
<LinearLayout> - vertical orientation
<Textview/>
<Textview/>
</LinearLayout> - vertical orientation
</LinearLayout> - horizontal orientation.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set the orientation of the Linear Layout as horizontal. This will make all the children (in your case, ImageView, TextView name and TextView description) to be horizontally laid out next to each other.

There are many ways to do this. 
1 way to achieve this is by using RelativeLayout and then you can use

`android:layout_toBottomOf="@id/textview_name"`

to get the description textview to be below the name text view.

For the image view, you can use the property

`android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"`

to make the image view to stick to the left border. Please experiment with RelativeLayout to get the desired result.

Please use this codelab from Google to use ContraintLayout. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html#0